# Type Error: Cannot read the property of ID of undefined (discord.js)

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

Here is the code that causes the problem. It is in my main file (index.js)

```
let prefix = db.get(`prefix_${message.guild.id}`)
  if(prefix === null) prefix = PREFIX;
```

Here is some of my setprefix command:

```
(args[2] === "!") {
      db.delete(`prefix_${message.guild.id}`)
     return await message.channel.send("Reseted Prefix ✅")
    }
    
    db.set(`prefix_${message.guild.id}`, args[2])
  await message.channel.send(`Succesfully set the Bot Prefix to **"${args[2]}"**`)
```

Comment: Are you sure you're showing the relevant code?

Comment: Can you send the exact line of code, where the error occurs?

Comment: @Jannik Schmidtke it says /index.js:158 and line 158 is ```let prefix = db.get(`prefix_${message.guild.id}`)
  if(prefix === null) prefix = PREFIX;``` But the error only happens sometimes not all the time

Comment: its happening more frequently now